# different cart content for different woocommerce mini-cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

i have two different categories for woocommerce products, when i'm on category A page there should be products in mini cart section from category A only.

and when on category B there should only be category b products in mini cart.

i have mini-cart.php and other is mini-cart-b.php

when i click "add to cart" it out puts perfect data against category only products, but when i click on category B LINK mini cart shows category A products :( and this is the problem. and if i click add to cart on category B page than it gets updated with products against this category.

what i want to understand is when page loads how data is populated in mini-cart which file is being used or data comes from session ?

if it comes from session how i can edit it on page redirect

this is how i'm showing different products for different categories

first creating index on `WC()->cart->get_cart()` object

```
foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {

            $terms = wp_get_post_terms($cart_item['data']->id, 'product_cat' );
            $products_by_categories[$terms[0]->name][] = $cart_item;
            $cart_keys[$cart_item['product_id']] = $cart_item_key;
        }
```

than looping through products_by_categories

```
foreach ( $products_by_categories as $cat_name => $cart_items ) { // code goes here; }
```

listing products

```
foreach ( $cart_items as $tmp_index => $cart_item ) { //code goes here;}
```

Comment: have you check this filter hook woocommerce_cart_item_product. i hope it will help you.

Comment: Are you trying to actually create two separate carts (if so, for what purpose?), or are you only trying to limit the _display_ of the items in one general cart in certain places of your website? (And if the latter, do you need it to display the total price only for those products that get displayed, or still the overall cart total?)

Comment: @misorude i have to different mini-carts .. mini-cart-a.php, mini-cart-b.php ..and both will have different content by category, bot cart output different style and content but if i move from one category to other it shows previous category style and content

Comment: You are talking about script files here, that is not what I meant - I meant what _functionality_ you want to achieve by this; are these supposed to be two different carts from which the user can create two different orders separately (and if so, have you checked whether that is even technically possible?), or do you want this for _display_ purposes only, but the user will submit the whole content of those carts in one single step at the end to create one single order?

Comment: display purposes only, but the user will submit the whole content of those carts in one single step at the end to create one single order, Yes exactly! ... main problem is i'm using some theme ... and how mini cart is populated on page refresh ... because the files mini-cart-a.php and mini-cart-b.php is not being used ... if i write exit on top ... it still works

Comment: Now!! what i'm going to do is ... create hidden file in category pages ... fire jquery auto click ... send ajax request and repopulate the mini cart ...using different files, that is being called!!

Comment: @Yasir I am working on something similar right now, did you ever manage to get this to work? I want to show two different carts on the same page at the same time.